# PyYaml: sequence node tag missing when parsing yaml

Tags: python, yaml, aws-cloudformation, pyyaml

I working on project which needs me to parse AWS CFN template and inject some code, and currently facing some problems when parsing sequence node in the yaml file.

**Issue 1**

The code snippet:

```
import yaml
class Equals(yaml.YAMLObject):
    yaml_tag = '!Equals'
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val

    def __repr__(self):
        return '!Equals {}'.format(self.val)

    @classmethod
    def from_yaml(cls, loader, node):
        return loader.construct_yaml_seq(node)

    @classmethod
    def to_yaml(dumper, data):
        return dumper.represent_list(cls.yaml_tag, data.val)


yaml_doc = """
Test:
  Context: !Equals
    - test1
    - test2
"""

yaml.SafeLoader.add_constructor('!Equals', Equals.from_yaml)
yaml.SafeDumper.add_representer(Equals, Equals.to_yaml)

docs = yaml.safe_load(yaml_doc)
print(yaml.safe_dump(docs))
```

**The output**:

```
Test:
  Context:
  - test1
  - test2
```

**The expected output**: the same as the `yaml_doc` variable.

**Issue 2**

In the template, you can use `>-` or `|` to add multiple lines, however, when I parsed yaml file via PyYAML, `>-` and `|` are missing in the generated yaml.

Please let me know if you know how to deal with those problems